# Expected number of buckets with at least one ball

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This question is related to this question: [Given K balls and N buckets what is the expected number of occupied buckets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114443/given-k-balls-and-n-buckets-what-is-the-expected-number-of-occupied-buckets)

The question is:

> Given $K$ balls and $N$ buckets how do you calculate the expected number of buckets with at least $1$ ball. Each ball is put in a bucket chosen at random with a uniform probability distribution. Assume also $K ≤ N$.

The first part of the answer goes like this:

> I will assume that we are throwing balls sequentially towards the buckets, with at any stage each bucket equally likely to receive a ball, and independence between throws. Then the probability that bucket $i$ has no balls in it after $K$ balls have been thrown is equal to
>   $$\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^K.$$

I had a different way of calculating this probability: counting the number of ways the $K$ balls can be put into $N-1$ buckets (all except bucket $i$), and dividing that by the number of ways $K$ balls can be put into $N$ buckets. I can use stars and bars to calculate each. Why does this method not work in this case? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: How is this question different from the linked question?

Comment: @GregMartin I guess the question is not how to find the expected value but "what is my error in this proof?" The original post does not help in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you've mixed up $N$ and $K$ between the given answer and your method.  For the rest of this answer, I'll assume you meant

> I had a different way of calculating this probability: counting the number of ways the $K$ balls can be put into $N−1$ buckets (all except bucket $i$), and dividing that by the number of ways $K$ balls can be put into $N$ buckets. I can use stars and bars to calculate each. Why does this method not work in this case? I'm a bit confused.

For this to make any sense to compute the probability, all the outcomes you're counting need to be equally likely.  Is this true?  Well, let's just take $N=2$ and $K=2$ for example.  Using your logic, the outcomes are

1. Two balls in bucket 1
2. One ball in bucket 1, one ball in bucket 2
3. Two balls in bucket 2

Are these equally likely to occur?  No.  Outcomes 1 and 3 each occur with probability $1/4,$ but outcome 2 occurs with probability $1/2.$

Comment: Oh now I understand, thanks! So the stars and bars method can be used to count the number of ways reliably (in case the items being put into buckets are identical), but when calculating probability, the method fails.

Answer (score 1):

In your second method you have changed the problem from $K$ balls to $N$ balls.

The number of ways to put $K$ balls in $N-1$ buckets is $(N-1)^K$

The number of ways to put $K$ balls in $N$ buckets is $N^K$

Dividing gives the same answer as your first method.